# Irreducible components of a morphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ and $Y$ be algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ and $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ a morphism.

1. Let $Z$ be an irreducible component of $Y$. When is $f^{-1}(Z)$ an irreducible component of $X$?
2. If $U$ is an irreducible component of $X$, when will $f(U)$ be an irreducible component of $Y$?

I just wanted to know where I can find references with results that help me find answers to the above questions.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, what is your definition of variety? Since you are talking about irreducible components, I assume that you mean "reduced, separated scheme of finite type over $\mathbb C$," but allowing varieties to be reducible also allows for fairly trivial examples like for 1), let $X = L_1 \cup L_2$ be the union of two lines in $\mathbb P^2$ which intersect in a point $p$, let $Y = L_1$, and let $f$ be the morphism which is the identity on $L_1$ but contracts $L_2$ to $p$. Then $Y$ is irreducible with reducible preimage.

Comment: @TabesBridges. Thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: @TabesBridges. Can you give me references in this direction? Thank you.

Comment: Regarding these types of questions? I would imagine that a thorough study of properties of irreducible components is to be found in EGA, The Stacks Project, and few other places.

Comment: @TabesBridges.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "Let X and Y be algebraic varieties over C and f:X⟶Y a morphism. Let Z be an irreducible component of Y. When is f−1(Z) an irreducible component of X? If U is an irreducible component of X, when will f(U) be an irreducible component of Y?"

**Answer:** If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a map of noetherian schemes, you may decompose $X$ and $Y$ into irreducible components $X\cong \cup X_i, Y\cong \cup Y_j$.

If $X$ is irreducible it follows $f(X)$ is irreducible for the following reason: Assume not and that $f(X)=Y_1 \cup Y_2$ is the union of two closed distinct subschemes. It follows $X=f^{-1}(Y_1) \cup f^{-1}(Y_2)$ and $f^{-1}(Y_1) \neq f^{-1}(Y_2)$ is a union of two closed distinct subschemes, contradicting the assumtion that $X$ was irreducible.

Comment: Hello @hm2020. Thanks for answering one more question I asked on this forum. I learn a lot from them, as they are clear and objective, that is, straight to the point. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, @hm2020.   Assuming $X$ and $Y$ reduced schemes and $f$ a surjective morphism, then is (1) true? Thank you.